# how to instantiate an es6 class after it's been bundled into a function by webpack

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, es6-class

I was following an es6 classes tutorial and made a nice little d3 visualization. Then I made a second, and thought I should do something about bundling them into a library, so initially tried modules (then discovered browsers don't support them yet), and then I installed webpack 1.13 and used `require()` (because although it seemed like `import` should work, it didn't; not supported until 2.0).

Only, now instead of `export default class Foo(data, args)` in my bundle.js I've got `var Foo =   function () { function Foo(data, args) ...`.

The interpreter just complains when I try to `Foo.Foo(data, args)`, but my intuition here is that pretend-instanting a frankenclass this way probably isn't what webpack intends? And yes, I could just concatenate all my module files into my own bundle.js and then go `new Foo()`, but I'm trying to use a proper bundling tool.

I feel like there's quite a gap in the online documentation between what's "possible" in ES6, and how you actually make it happen in webpack.

***What's the step-by-step way of bundling modules with webpack such that you can instatiate your classes from the bundle in your index.js script?***

---

Appendix: (What I've done so far)

```
├── bundle.js             #supposed to bundle Foo and Bar
├── bundle.js.map
├── index.html            #include bundle.js and index.js before </body>
├── index.js              #want to be able to new Foo() and Bar()
├── js
|    ├── foo.js           Foo() lives here
|    └── bar.js           Bar() lives here
├── LICENSE
├── node_modules
|    └── (stuff)
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── test
|    └── (stuff)
└── webpack.config.js     # builds without errors
```

Comment: `so initially tried modules,  (then discovered browsers don't support them yet),`  you can use them now, https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

Comment: Also if you want bleeding edge javascript, there is also http://jspm.io/ that will auto babel your files.

Comment: Thanks, I may go with systemjs here, but would like to know how to do this with webpack (for interoperability with and existing project that uses webpack)

Comment: In what way do you mean interoperability with other webpack project's?  Webpack is mainly just a bundler, if your webpack project can interface with a pre-compiled webpack bundle, so can any javascript file.  The only exception I would say to this, is if the webpack project had been compiled as a DLL, but not sure that's something that's done very often.

Comment: No, as in I don't want the project to use different js frameworks for different pages. Another engineer is already using webpack for most of his React stuff, and one page just happens to need a d3 vizualization that I thought I'd make some headway on. It's for consistency.

Comment: Then you just compile into the existing webpack config.  IOW: Make your d3 stuff, pass him the source.  He then just `require('yourstuff')`.   Your webpack config will just be for you, for testing purposes.

Comment: Exactly, so how do I get it working then so that I can get myself a `new Foo()`?

Comment: Everything in webpack bundle is private, so if you want Foo() to be available outside the bundle, then you can place it on the Global.  Then you can do  `new Foo()` from anywhere in the page, or even console.  You could use the https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader , or just for testing you could even do,,  window.Foo = Foo;

Comment: OK, would you mind putting that in an answer with some example code? (I don't know what the "Global" you refer to is; I'm new to webpack). Probably worth restating that webpack bundles are private too, so that any subsequent visitors like me don't think "Oh modules + webpack = insta-library!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack is a bundler. That means after you run webpack, it parses all your files and puts them into one, (or more if using something like CommonsChunkPlugin).

Everything inside the bundle is then private, so if you want to share your classes, code etc.  you will then to need to expose them, https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader  can do this, but in essence all it's doing is placing stuff on the global namespace, in browsers the global namespace is usually the `window` object.

A better approach though to sharing code with other webpack uses, is for you to just show him were your code is, and then he can compile into his webpack bundle,. He can even do automatic bundle splitting with  `require.ensure`, this would be handy if say your Class is not used very often, so it would load on-demand.

Hope the above makes sense, as I remember when I first started using webpack, it did seem overwhelming at times, and the documenation isn't the greatest for beginners.